# Html clone in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code

```
<div class="render-form-editlayout-10">
  <div class="formeo-render formeo" id="formeo-rendered-1">
    <div class="f-stage" id="afd81782-0230-4bbf-a39d-774ba6b3f6cf">
      <div class="f-row" id="78501c81-ce36-4703-ae99-7e086a95c0d7">
        <div class="f-render-column" id="71dac9e6-03ed-4294-b60f-8d2466d1aa17" style="width: 100%;">
          <h1 id="5baec553-c31c-4d0b-a138-6d338deb1f4b">Contact</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="44a64baa-64e5-44ad-af51-bed0a0abf3ae">
        <div class="f-render-column" id="95128be9-b2cb-4c82-aea2-4dd84b247ac4" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_first_name" id="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="f-render-column" id="17193931-bd81-452e-95ba-591f2246eb37" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">Sur Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_sur_name" id="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="9ba99767-5ea4-40b2-b0a4-df252b210a3c">
        <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="4fe9abe0-6944-4504-896b-44adfa58ade8" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_email" id="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="e5bd3083-fb17-4453-a875-b6024db9461f">
        <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="b87b0913-9286-4233-afcb-e568e3017092" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">Phone</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contact_phone" id="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="render-form-editlayout-10">
  <div class="formeo-render formeo" id="formeo-rendered-1">
    <div class="f-stage" id="afd81782-0230-4bbf-a39d-774ba6b3f6cf">
      <div class="f-row" id="44a64baa-64e5-44ad-af51-bed0a0abf3ae">
        <div class="f-render-column" id="95128be9-b2cb-4c82-aea2-4dd84b247ac4" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_first_name" id="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="f-render-column" id="17193931-bd81-452e-95ba-591f2246eb37" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">Sur Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_sur_name" id="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="9ba99767-5ea4-40b2-b0a4-df252b210a3c">
        <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="4fe9abe0-6944-4504-896b-44adfa58ade8" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_email" id="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="e5bd3083-fb17-4453-a875-b6024db9461f">
        <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="b87b0913-9286-4233-afcb-e568e3017092" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">Phone</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contact_phone" id="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success cloneMe " data-id="10">+</button>
```

[**Js Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wo73s4ky/) for above code

So when you click the + button it should clone the html .

Now When It's cloned I want to make it look like this

[**Js Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/56sfx5ur/)

The catch is the name of the input type should be incremental like , name_1 , name_2

I am really confused how to do that

**Update**

As mentioned in one of the answers below the Id of the div can be accssed using the `data-id` of the button . Then My question is  ? is it possible to just get the input type and change there name+data-id and append ?

[image]

Comment: pfff that's not possible :)

Comment: you have duplicated IDs...

Comment: why dont you use jquery to iterate and change it manually?

Comment: @gaetanoM I mean , Its okay to change structure , but I need those field replicated actually

Comment: @MateiMihai How about I get the html as object and iterate over it to see what I need and then add it back , Looks confusing but can you give me some other idea ?\

Comment: @amitwadhwani thats what I am thinking but don't know how to do that , I am okay with changing the Html structure but the input type should be replicated with new name

Comment: @Vikram The name shouldn't be incremental.. they must be defined as arrays `name="contact_phone[]"`

Comment: @MateiMihai I know I can do that , But the back end api will have to be changed a lot to facilitate that , When user submits the form , so the complete form is submited as a Json data , and the api right now only acepts one level of iteration , when I have an array it will break I think

Comment: But I am going to read it and see

Comment: Can you change the markup anyway you want or you have some limitations?

Comment: @RamyNasr I can't its Auto generated by a plugin called Formeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of a flagrant abuse of template literals, but here's a simplified version just for fun - as a general practice I would lean toward an actual templating library for this sort of thing (Underscore has a fairly easy template function, for example).

```js
addSubform = (function(){
  n = 0
  container = $('#container')
  return function(){
    n += 1
    container.append(`<div class="subform" id="subform${n}">
First Name: <input type="text" id="fname_${n}" name="fname_${n}" /><br />
Surname: <input type="text" id="sname_${n}" name="sname_${n}" /><br />
<hr />
</div>`)
  }
})()

$(document).ready(function(){
  addSubform()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
<button onclick="addSubform()">+</button>
```

Here's another option that I generally wouldn't recommend if you have any viable alternatives, but it uses regex to find the name attributes and append a suffix.  It doesn't work quite as intended, but I think it does enough to illustrate the concept. If you inspect with your dev tools, you'll see that the name attributes are being incremented.

I used closures in both examples in order to manage scope. That's a personal preference, and is not critical to solving your particular issue.

```js
//I would probably not put this in a global,
//but since it's unclear it's being determined client-side,
//I'm considering that concern out of scope for this question.
//var formNum 

buildForm = function(formNum) {
  /*A lot going on in this line - call the Array's slice method
  against the HTML element collection matching the class name "f-row",
  supplying an index (zero-based) of 1 for the start. This effectively
  removes the first element. Then use .reduce to convert the HTML of
  the remaining elements to a string.
  */
  var base = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName('render-form-editlayout-' + formNum)[0].getElementsByClassName('f-row'), 1)
    .reduce(function(b,e){return b += e.outerHTML},"")
  
  var suffix = 0
  return function() {
    suffix += 1
    return base.replace(/name="([a-z_]+)"/gm,'name="$1_' + suffix + '"')
  }
}

addForm = function(formNum, builder){
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName('render-form-editlayout-' + formNum)[0].getElementsByClassName('f-stage')[0]
  return function() {
    container.innerHTML += builder()
  }
}

makeCloneEvent = function(num) {
 return addForm(num, buildForm(num))
}

$('.cloneMe').each(
 function() {
    el = $(this)
    el.on('click', makeCloneEvent(el.data('id')))
  }
)
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form_container">
<div class="render-form-editlayout-10 form-model">
  <div class="formeo-render formeo" id="formeo-rendered-1">
    <div class="f-stage" id="afd81782-0230-4bbf-a39d-774ba6b3f6cf">
      <div class="f-row" id="78501c81-ce36-4703-ae99-7e086a95c0d7">
        <div class="f-render-column" id="71dac9e6-03ed-4294-b60f-8d2466d1aa17" style="width: 100%;">
          <h1 id="5baec553-c31c-4d0b-a138-6d338deb1f4b">Contact</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="44a64baa-64e5-44ad-af51-bed0a0abf3ae">
        <div class="f-render-column" id="95128be9-b2cb-4c82-aea2-4dd84b247ac4" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_first_name" id="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="f-render-column" id="17193931-bd81-452e-95ba-591f2246eb37" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">Sur Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_sur_name" id="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="9ba99767-5ea4-40b2-b0a4-df252b210a3c">
        <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="4fe9abe0-6944-4504-896b-44adfa58ade8" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_email" id="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="e5bd3083-fb17-4453-a875-b6024db9461f">
        <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="b87b0913-9286-4233-afcb-e568e3017092" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">Phone</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contact_phone" id="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <button  class="cloneMe" data-id='10'>Add +</button>
```

Comment: I like the 2nd answer but there is one small problem when I clone everything gets clone the button and Heading also is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: @Vikram Changing the selector that I'm assigning to the `base` variable should do it. Ideally, you would just wrap the form fields in an element of some kind - probably a div. If that's not possible, I think it will take a little bit more creativity.

Comment: have a look on this line of code mentioned in one of the answer `new_form.find('.f-row:first').remove();` I was trying to implement this in your code, But it doesn't work

Comment: If it worked, it would add extra manipulation each time the new form is created. I think we prefer to do the opposite: select all the f-row elements *except* the first. It will be a couple hours before I can work on it, but I think I see a fix.

Comment: @Vikram Header/button should now work correctly in the second snippet.

Comment: now you stopped using `render-form-editlayout-10` so actually thats important if you see my `data-id` of the button its same as the last digit of the class `render-form-editlayout-10` so actually it should be dynamic , and look for the class `render-form-editlayout-'+id`

Comment: Okay, I've modified it to daisy-chain that class selector in.  In my example, the id is represented by the `formNum` variable, but you can change it as needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153377/discussion-between-vikram-and-mic).

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56sfx5ur/3/).**

It will be more efficient to name your fields as array using `[]` like :

```
<div class="render-form-editlayout-10 form-model">
  <div class="formeo-render formeo" id="formeo-rendered-1">
    <div class="f-stage" id="afd81782-0230-4bbf-a39d-774ba6b3f6cf">
      <div class="f-row" id="78501c81-ce36-4703-ae99-7e086a95c0d7">
        <div class="f-render-column" id="71dac9e6-03ed-4294-b60f-8d2466d1aa17" style="width: 100%;">
          <h1 id="5baec553-c31c-4d0b-a138-6d338deb1f4b">Contact</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="44a64baa-64e5-44ad-af51-bed0a0abf3ae">
        <div class="f-render-column" id="95128be9-b2cb-4c82-aea2-4dd84b247ac4" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_first_name[]" id="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="f-render-column" id="17193931-bd81-452e-95ba-591f2246eb37" style="width: 50%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">Sur Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_sur_name[]" id="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="9ba99767-5ea4-40b2-b0a4-df252b210a3c">
        <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="4fe9abe0-6944-4504-896b-44adfa58ade8" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_email[]" id="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="f-row" id="e5bd3083-fb17-4453-a875-b6024db9461f">
        <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="b87b0913-9286-4233-afcb-e568e3017092" style="width: 100%;">
          <div class="f-field-group">
            <label for="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">Phone</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control[]" name="contact_phone" id="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success cloneMe " data-id="10">+</button>
```

Then by adding a class to your main div example `form-model` you could clone the form by attaching the click event to the button like :

```
$('.cloneMe').click(function(){
  var new_form = $('.form-model').clone(true); //Clone form

  new_form.find('.f-row:first').remove(); //Remove title 'Contact' from the clone

  $('.form-model').append(new_form); //append new form
});
```

**NOTE :** The only problem will be the duplicate id's when id attribute should be unique, so if you could avoid the id's in the original HTML code it will be better to validate your HTML.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually its a form builder that generates the form , And I am trying to add my own hack to add some features :'(

Comment: So you could adjust the generated form (add `[]` to names and remove ids) when it was ready then clone it on click.

Comment: If I add `[]` then in the backend Ill have to change the api as well which accepts the complete form as Json , And creates a Table with the name of the input type as table header and value as value

Comment: Aaah then you need realy to adjust them as you say, check this one https://jsfiddle.net/56sfx5ur/7/

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is:

- clone the **render-form-editlayout-10** div
- for each sub cloned element with an **id** add a postfix using the button **data-id**
- increment the button data-id

```js
$('.cloneMe').on('click', function (e) {
    var idToAppend = $(this).data('id');
    $(this).data('id', idToAppend + 1);
    $('div.render-form-editlayout-10:first').clone().find('[id]').attr('id', function (idx, val) {
        var newId = (this.name == undefined) ? val + idToAppend : this.name + '_' + idToAppend;
        if ((this.name != undefined)) {
            $(this).attr('name', newId);
            console.log('For elements with name the new ID is: ' +
                    newId + ' new Name is: ' + newId);
        }
        return newId;
    }).closest('div.render-form-editlayout-10').insertBefore(this);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="render-form-editlayout-10">
    <div class="formeo-render formeo" id="formeo-rendered-1">
        <div class="f-stage" id="afd81782-0230-4bbf-a39d-774ba6b3f6cf">
            <div class="f-row" id="78501c81-ce36-4703-ae99-7e086a95c0d7">
                <div class="f-render-column" id="71dac9e6-03ed-4294-b60f-8d2466d1aa17" style="width: 100%;">
                    <h1 id="5baec553-c31c-4d0b-a138-6d338deb1f4b">Contact</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="f-row" id="44a64baa-64e5-44ad-af51-bed0a0abf3ae">
                <div class="f-render-column" id="95128be9-b2cb-4c82-aea2-4dd84b247ac4" style="width: 50%;">
                    <div class="f-field-group">
                        <label for="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contact_first_name" id="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-render-column" id="17193931-bd81-452e-95ba-591f2246eb37" style="width: 50%;">
                    <div class="f-field-group">
                        <label for="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">Sur Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contact_sur_name" id="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="f-row" id="9ba99767-5ea4-40b2-b0a4-df252b210a3c">
                <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="4fe9abe0-6944-4504-896b-44adfa58ade8" style="width: 100%;">
                    <div class="f-field-group">
                        <label for="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contact_email" id="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="f-row" id="e5bd3083-fb17-4453-a875-b6024db9461f">
                <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="b87b0913-9286-4233-afcb-e568e3017092" style="width: 100%;">
                    <div class="f-field-group">
                        <label for="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">Phone</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contact_phone" id="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success cloneMe" data-id="10">+</button>
```

Comment: can you add that to the name as well like a new name contact_first_name_1, contact_first_nname_2

Comment: yes almost there , But next time when its cloning its doing clone of all the existing rather than just one , Like if there are two , then next clone it becomes 4 it should be 3 right

Comment: You can add simply the **:first** selector in order to clone only the first. It's not so hard.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: `$('.cloneMe').on('click', function(e) {
    var idToAppend = $(this).data('id');
    $(this).data('id', idToAppend + 1);
    $('div.render-form-editlayout-10').clone(":first").find('[id]').attr('id', function(idx, val) {
        var newId = (this.name == undefined) ? val + idToAppend : this.name + '_' + idToAppend;
        if ((this.name != undefined)) {
 $(this).attr('name', newId);console.log('For elements with name the new ID is: ' +newId + ' new Name is: ' + newId);}return newId; }).closest('div.render-form-editlayout-10').insertBefore(this);})` I tired this its not working

Comment: @Vikram Sorry. The **:first** selector goes only here: **$('div.render-form-editlayout-10:first')**.  Snippet updated. Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did a small change on your code to make it work. I hope you don't mind. Please change as you need.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MMRahman/56sfx5ur/2/)

```
      <div class="render-form-editlayout-10">
        <div class="formeo-render formeo" id="formeo-rendered-1">

          <div class="f-stage" id="afd81782-0230-4bbf-a39d-774ba6b3f6cf">
            <div class="f-row" id="78501c81-ce36-4703-ae99-7e086a95c0d7">
              <div class="f-render-column" id="71dac9e6-03ed-4294-b60f-8d2466d1aa17" style="width: 100%;">
                <h1 id="5baec553-c31c-4d0b-a138-6d338deb1f4b">Contact</h1></div>
            </div>

            <div id="cloneme">
            <div class="f-row" id="44a64baa-64e5-44ad-af51-bed0a0abf3ae">
              <div class="f-render-column" id="95128be9-b2cb-4c82-aea2-4dd84b247ac4" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="f-field-group">
                  <label for="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">First name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="contact_first_name" id="293053b9-9769-4b06-8156-01d7a15995b3">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="f-render-column" id="17193931-bd81-452e-95ba-591f2246eb37" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="f-field-group">
                  <label for="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">Sur Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="contact_sur_name" id="3d276a4f-1dff-4594-8fe8-56ac1acf58e4">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="f-row" id="9ba99767-5ea4-40b2-b0a4-df252b210a3c">
              <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="4fe9abe0-6944-4504-896b-44adfa58ade8" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="f-field-group">
                  <label for="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" name="contact_email" id="8379e16f-f468-47c4-8149-ba606d4310ad">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="f-row" id="e5bd3083-fb17-4453-a875-b6024db9461f">
              <div class="f-render-column f-render-column f-render-column" id="b87b0913-9286-4233-afcb-e568e3017092" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="f-field-group">
                  <label for="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">Phone</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contact_phone" id="a54606a2-679b-4e9c-8b90-f5f2c6e79ef0">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<button id= "clone" class="btn btn-success cloneMe " data-id="10">+</button>


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#clone").click(function(){
            $("#cloneme").clone().appendTo("#afd81782-0230-4bbf-a39d-774ba6b3f6cf");
        });
    });
```

Comment: _The catch is the name of the input type should be incremental like , name_1 , name_2_ where's this ?

Comment: As I said , It just a basic Idea how it should be done.  Also mentioned "Please change as you need".  Unless he want us to do the job..

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to do this if you can not use the `name='something[]'` pattern suggested in previous answers, is to do the following:

1. Have a template of all the form elements you want to clone ( all the markup )
2. Have a string in this markup that should be replaced with the incremental index every time you are cloning. ( e.g. `<input name="firstname__index__" ... />` )
3. Every time you want to clone, just search and replace all instances of `__index__` in your HTML with your increment before appending the new HTML to your page.

Consider something like that:

```
$clonedForm.find('input').each(function (i, ele) {
    var $input = $(ele);
    var name = $input.attr('name').replace('__index__', increment);
    $input.attr('name', name);
});
```